# Can we use a block in deep learning model that is instantiated ones, for multiple times. would it have different parameters or the same?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

for example

```
   self.conv_transformer = Transformer(dim=128, proj_kernel=3, kv_proj_stride=2, depth=3, heads=6, dim_head=64, mlp_mult=4, dropout=0.)

    
    



def forward(self, img):
    x1 = self.encoder1(img)
    x2 = self.encoder2(x1)
    x3 = self.conv_transformer(x2)
    x4 = self.conv_transformer(x3)
    x5 = self.conv_transformer(x4)
    x6 = self.conv_transformer(x5)
    x7 = self.conv_transformer(x6)
```

here I instantiated transformer block only once, but I am passing the values from it multiple times. Should I consider it as deeper network?

This code I wrote to modify u-net model

Comment: Hellow Satyam, and welcome to SO! The question is relevant, but the language and formatting is a little off. Consider e.g. removing uncessacary blanklines in the code. Furthermore, please state the question clearly in the body of the text, not only in the question title. Currently, you have two different questions in the body and title.

Answer (score 1):

This would be considered as only containing a single transformer block. The transformer block will have the same parameters no matter how many times you call it. Thus, you should declare different transformer blocks, 5 in your case, if you want to have 5 different blocks with different parameters